# Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos not embedding GPS information in Photos

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand

My Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos is not embedding GPS information(Latitude/Longitude) in Photos taken from the phone camera.
I have enabled GPS option in main settings, and also set the GPS tag in the camera settings.
The latitude and longitude information is not appearing in the photo details.
I do not wish to enable the "Mobile Data" option.  I do not need the location information like place name, etc... I only need latitude and longitude information.
What other setting am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It could simply be that the phone doesn't have a GPS fix when you take the photo. It might be different in your phone's camera app, but most camera apps start asking for the position when you start the app, and if there isn't a fix when you hit the 'shutter release', they save the photo anyway, rather than holding you up waiting for a GPS fix. Getting an accurate position can take some minutes if you're hidden from the sky, so it's easy to take the photo first without realising.

Check the location icon in the notification bar, and be sure it has stopped blinking before you take the photo.

Comment: I use the default camera app which came with the phone.  I have taken photo inside and outside building, but no luck.  There is no location icon in the notification bar.  Is there some setting i am missing?

Comment: If there's no location icon at all, then the camera app's not trying to get the location. Double-check the camera settings.